# What is the rationale behind the way generics expand in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have recently been learning Typescript, I really like it just for the types.

One thing I really like is these 'conditional types' which allow me to write things like

```
type W<T> = T extends Array<infer R> ? R : any;
type Z = string[];
type X = W<Z>; // string
```

Really useful.

I have been writing my own 'utility' types to learn the typescript system better, a built in utility to Typescript is 'Extract' which takes from T the types which are assignable to U.

```
type Z = { a: "hi"; b: string } | { a: "bye"; b: number };
type W = Extract<Z, { a: "hi" }>; // { a: "hi", b: string }
```

Really nice as well, I was trying to work out how to implement it myself and couldn't do so, eventually I found out that it is essentially

```
type MyExtract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

Which I find a bit bizarre, one of the rules I expect in life is that equality is transitive, so, perhaps naively I would expect that

```
type Z = { a: "hi"; b: string } | { a: "bye"; b: number };
type MyExtract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
type W = MyExtract<Z, { a: "hi" }>; // { a: "hi", b: string }
type ShouldBeSameAsW = Z extends { a: "hi" } ? Z : never; // never
```

Here on the 4th line I have substituted the T and U from the third line into the second line, but it produces a different result.

I came to understand that the way Typescript works is that the third line when it actually evaluates the right hand side,  looks at T, if it is a union type it applies the right handside to every element of the union, and takes the union of that, so that actually W is like

```
type ShouldBeSameAsW = { a: "hi"; b: string } extends { a: "hi" }
    ? { a: "hi"; b: string }
    : never | { a: "bye"; b: number } extends { b: "bye" }
    ? { a: "bye"; b: number }
    : never;
```

Which is fine, I guess, except that I don't understand the reasoning that means that it's sensible for it to work this way, I'm also reasonably confident that Typescript wouldn't go about making equality not transitive, so I don't understand how it isn't based on the above example.

So my question is

What is the rationale behind making type

```
MyExtract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

expand in this weird way, how does it not render '=' non transitive, and why is there not just some additional syntax which is more transparent for this splitting up of T into its parts?

Comment: See the documentation on [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), a special behavior that only kicks in for conditional types of the form `T extends ... ? ... : ...` where `T` is the name of a generic type parameter.  If `T` is a non-generic type, it doesn't happen.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to answer "why isn't there just some different syntax for distributive conditional types" in a way that isn't just opinion.  You could pore through the [relevant pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) but I don't see much discussion of syntax in there.